# jquery image not loading problem

Tags: jquery, image, preload

does anybody knows how to check if an image loads properly. I have a script that preloads images and what I wanted to do is if the image doesn't exists, which causes my script not to end, I would just make the attribute "src" to be a default value

```
image.load(function(){
 //it never reache here if the image doesn't exist
}).attr('src','a non existing image');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var image = $('<img>').appendTo('body');

image.load(function() {
    // image is found and loaded
}).error(function() {
    // image not loaded
    image.attr('src','default-image.jpg');
}).attr('src','a non existing image');
```